# How do I abort the execution of a Python script?

Tags: python, syntax, scripting, exit

I have a simple Python script that I want to stop executing if a condition is met.

For example:

```
done = True
if done:
    # quit/stop/exit
else:
    # do other stuff
```

Essentially, I am looking for something that behaves equivalently to the 'return' keyword in the body of a function which allows the flow of the code to exit the function and not execute the remaining code.

Answer (score 333, accepted):

To exit a script you can use,

```
import sys
sys.exit()
```

You can also provide an exit status value, usually an integer.

```
import sys
sys.exit(0)
```

Exits with zero, which is generally interpreted as success.  Non-zero codes are usually treated as errors.  The default is to exit with zero.

```
import sys
sys.exit("aa! errors!")
```

Prints "aa! errors!" and exits with a status code of 1.

There is also an _exit() function in the os module.  The [sys.exit()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exit) function raises a SystemExit exception to exit the program, so try statements and cleanup code can execute.  The os._exit() version doesn't do this.  It just ends the program without doing any cleanup or flushing output buffers, so it shouldn't normally be used.

The [Python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os._exit) indicate that os._exit() is the normal way to end a child process created with a call to os.fork(), so it does have a use in certain circumstances.

Comment: `sys.stdout.flush()` paired with `os._exit(0)` was exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: This does not work on my Anaconda python.
sys.exit()
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-26-86e3364fd793>", line 1, in <module>
    sys.exit()

AttributeError: 'System' object has no attribute 'exit'

Comment: The current Python 3.7.0 issues a warning when using `sys.exit(0)`: `SystemExit: 0
C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py:2969: UserWarning: To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.
  warn("To exit: use 'exit', 'quit', or Ctrl-D.", stacklevel=1)`. Is it OK? Does it appear only because I'm using iPython?

Answer (score 22):

You could put the body of your script into a function and then you could return from that function.

```
def main():
  done = True
  if done:
    return
    # quit/stop/exit
  else:
    # do other stuff

if __name__ == "__main__":
  #Run as main program
  main()
```

Answer (score 21):

```
import sys
sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 21):

You can either use:

```
import sys
sys.exit(...)
```

or:

```
raise SystemExit(...)
```

The optional parameter can be an exit code or an error message. Both methods are identical. I used to prefer sys.exit, but I've lately switched to raising SystemExit, because it seems to stand out better among the rest of the code (due to the **raise** keyword).

Answer (score 6):

exit() should do the trick

Comment: THree seconds faster than me :P

Comment: And I even tested it in a shell first :-)

Comment: Damn you, I didn't see this/react in time (was also testing in the interpreter to be sure)  *shakes fist* ;)

Comment: this only works in version 2.5 and later

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
sys.exit("message")
```

It is like the perl

```
die("message")
```

if this is what you are looking for. It terminates the execution of the script even it is called from an imported module / def /function

Comment: did none of the answers suggested such an approach?

Answer (score 4):

exit() should do it.

Answer (score 3):

If the entire program should stop use sys.exit() otherwise just use an empty return.

Comment: `return` won't work outside a function.