# how do I halt execution in a python script?

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Programatically stop execution of python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543309/programatically-stop-execution-of-python-script)
>   [Terminating a Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73663/terminating-a-python-script)

I want to print a value, and then halt execution of the script.

Do I just use return?

Comment: There are different ways to terminate Python scripts. Can you post some code to give some context?

Comment: What the heck--how do you have 5.7K rep and ask this question?

Comment: Another duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179369/how-do-i-abort-the-execution-of-a-python-script

Comment: @John He has 726 questions and 4 answers -- you don't need to answer questions to amass rep

Comment: @Mark Nicely done; voted to close all of them except 73663

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use return inside the main function in you have one, but this isn't guaranteed to quit the script if there is more code after your call to main.

The simplest that nearly always works is [`sys.exit()`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.exit):

```
import sys
sys.exit()
```

Other possibilities:

- Raise an error which isn't caught.
- Let the execution point reach the end of the script.
- If you are in a thread other than the main thread use [`thread.interrupt_main()`](http://docs.python.org/library/thread.html#thread.interrupt_main).

Comment: You can only use `return` in a function, and just letting the execution point reach the end of the script isn't really "halting execution"

Comment: @Michael Mrozek: I disagree - reaching the end of the script is a way to halt execution. If he just wants to print "Hello world" then end the script then that's actually the most pythonic way to halt execution.

Answer (score 7):

There's `exit` function in `sys` module ( [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html) ):

```
import sys
sys.exit( 0 ) # 0 will be passed to OS
```

You can also

```
raise SystemExit
```

or any other exception that won't be caught.

Answer (score 6):

[sys.exit](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html)

Comment: It might be a good idea to mention that you need to import sys. It also might be a good idea to mention that you need parentheses to actually call the function. Without the parentheses it will do nothing.

Comment: +1 Read @Mark's comment; a bit lazy to edit my post.