# halt processing of program AND stop traceback?

Tags: python, traceback

I have a program that needs to stop processing altogether once a certain condition has been triggered - similar to this question: [How do I abort the execution of a Python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179369/how-do-i-abort-the-execution-of-a-python-script)

However, in my case, I want to capture the traceback that sys.exit() generates AND MOST IMPORTANTLY stop processing anything code blocks beyond that point. Can anyone help with this?

```
try:
    a = 'i' / 1
    print 'Does this work yet?'
except TypeError:
    print "I should stop processing now"
    try:
        sys.exit()
    except:
        pass
print 'I did not stop processing '
```

Comment: I've also tried try-except blocks of code, nested try-except blocks of code, and raise SystemExit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you are asking, as far as I know `sys.exit()` does not generate a traceback. If you try to execute your code as it is, `sys.exit()` raises an unhandled NameError exception because you have not imported the "sys" module. Surrounding the call to sys.exit() with a try/except block will capture the NameError exception, but it will also capture the normal exception raised by sys.exit(), as per the documentation:

> Exit from Python. This is implemented by raising the SystemExit
>   exception, so cleanup actions specified by finally clauses of try
>   statements are honored, and it is possible to intercept the exit
>   attempt at an outer level.

Here is a version that stops processing once it encounters an error.

```
import sys

try:
    a = 'i' / 1
    print 'Does this work yet?'
except TypeError:
    print "I should stop processing now"
    sys.exit()
print 'I did not stop processing '
```

If this code is in your main module, I suggest wrapping your entry-point code up like this:

```
import sys

def main():
    try:
        a = 'i' / 1
        print 'Does this work yet?'
    except TypeError:
        print "I should stop processing now"
        return 1
    print 'I did not stop processing '
    return 0

if __name__ == "__main__": sys.exit(main())
```

This way you only ever have one call to sys.exit(), and it returns an error code indicating if there was a problem. If your code is not in the top-level entry point, I suggest you just throw the exception up until it gets to the main() method, where it can then return the error code value. You can wrap the real exception in a new "StopMyApplicationException" that you have to define.

Oh, and if you want to print the traceback, you can use the `traceback` module, something like `traceback.print_exc()` will do the job.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the fact that system-exiting exceptions don't derive from [Exception](http://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.Exception):

```
try:
    a = 'i' / 1
    print 'Does this work yet?'
except TypeError:
    print "I should stop processing now"
    try:
        raise SystemExit
    except Exception:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get access to the *exception* that `sys.exit` generates, but it will have no traceback.

```
try:
    sys.exit()
except SystemExit as e:
    # do what you want with e, e.g.
    traceback.print_exc(e)
    raise
```

A bare `raise` in an `except` clause re-raises the caught exception.