# What is python's "abort"?

Tags: python

C uses `abort` to terminate the process by raising a SIGABRT signal. What is the equivalent `abort` in Python? Thanks.

Comment: I guess you could send a SIGABRT signal to the parent process? Why do you need this?

Comment: Are you looking for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/179369/how-do-i-abort-the-execution-of-a-python-script)?

Comment: I suspect however that just `sys.exit()` suffices for your needs.

Comment: No point tagging C, since the question isn't *about* C. Removed tag

Comment: Think in Python and your life will be easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import sys
sys.exit()
```

You can also give some text as a parameter to print the error message.

```
sys.exit("This is the error")
```

Comment: So, sys.exit is going to terminate the process, rather than shut down the whole python program, right?

Comment: @wad: What distinction are you trying to make there?

Comment: Since exit() only raises an exception, it will only exit the process when called from the main thread, and the exception is not intercepted.

Comment: No, this is normal exit. `os.abort()` calls C `abort`. Why is this question marked as duplicate when the linked questions do not aswer?