# ending a program early, not in a loop?

Tags: python

I'm attempting to make a short program that will return the factorial of a number, which works fine. The only problem I am having is getting the program to end if the user inputs a non-integer value.

```
num = input("input your number to be factorialised here!: ")

try:
    num1 = int(num)
except ValueError:
    print("That's not a number!")



if num1 < 0:
    print("You can't factorialise a negative number")
elif num1 == 0:
    print("the factorial of 0 is 1")
else:
        for i in range(1,num1+1):
            ans = ans * i
        print("the factorial of", num, "is", ans)
```

Comment: You need to define `ans`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if string input is a number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424716/how-to-check-if-string-input-is-a-number)

Comment: why are you asking such questions before previously researching here itself? it has been answer too many times: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424716/how-to-check-if-string-input-is-a-number, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19440952/how-do-i-check-if-raw-input-is-integer-in-python-2-7, http://www.101computing.net/number-only/ --> this is not a homework solving tool.

Comment: You could use regex too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Solution

There are better ways of doing this but given your code structure you can use `else`. See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions).

```
num = input("input your number to be factorialised here!: ")

try:
    num1 = int(num)
except ValueError:
    print("That's not a number!")
else:
    if num1 < 0:
        print("You can't factorialise a negative number")
    elif num1 == 0:
        print("the factorial of 0 is 1")
    else:
        ans = 1
        for i in range(1,num1+1):
            ans = ans * i
        print("the factorial of", num, "is", ans)
```

The `else` clause only executes if no exceptions are thrown.

#### Suggestions

So as not to give away answers to your homework, here are a couple suggestions that you should take a look at to clean up your code:

1. Can you use [range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) more efficiently? Hint: you can iterate over decreasing numbers by setting the `step` to a negative integer.
2. Can you find a way to get rid of the check `num1 == 0`?

Answer (score 3):

The OP is actually asking how to terminate the current script execution prematurely. The straightforward way to implement your idea is to use `sys.exit()` like

```
try:
    num1 = int(num)
except ValueError:
    sys.exit()
```

For more details, see this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179369/how-do-i-abort-the-execution-of-a-python-script).

Comment: It's a fairly trivial point, but using a non-zero exit status here might be slightly more proper.

Comment: I agree this causes the program to exit, but adding an `else` clause (or some other form of error handling) is the proper way to handle this.