# How to stop python program once condition is met (in jupyter notebook)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I want to know if Jupyter Notebook has a command to stop subsequent cells from running once the command has been given.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179369/how-do-i-abort-the-execution-of-a-python-script) and tried `sys.exit()` but some of the cells below the command are still being executed.

The structure of my script looks as follows:

```py
# tons of cells above
```

```py
if df["target"].mean() == 1:
    sys.exit("Condition met. Do not execute the cells below.")
```

```py
# tons of cells below
```

Ideally, none of the cells represented by `tons of cells below` should be executed if `df["target"].mean()` is `1`. Otherwise, I do want to the subsequent cells executed.

I suppose one solution would be to write the code of all the subsequent cells in an `else` statement inside the same cell where `sys.exit()` is written. However, I do not want to do this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try this instead of `sys.exit()`:

```
raise SystemExit("Stop right there!")
```