# Is there a way to stop a program from running if an input is incorrect? Python

Tags: python

I have been trying to write this code and I need a way of stopping the code if a certain input is incorrect, here is what I have so far:

```
first_name = input('PLEASE ENTER YOUR FIRST NAME: ')
last_name = input('PLEASE ENTER YOUR SURNAME: ')
print(f'Hello {first_name} {last_name}, before you enter.')

def age_det():
    age = input(f'How old are you?')
    converted_age = [int(age)]
  
    for num in converted_age: 
      while num>=18:
        print(f'Awesome, {first_name}, welcome to Blablabla')
        num += 100
      while num <= 18:
        break
      print(f'Sorry, {first_name}, but we require you to be at least 18 to enter Blablabla.')
      num += 100

age_det()
#I want the code to stop here if the age entered is under 18    

username = input('Before we start, please pick a username: ')

print(f'Woah! {username}, good choice!')
```

Comment: `if age < 18: sys.exit(1)` ...

Comment: it was previously answered at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543309/programmatically-stop-execution-of-python-script
and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73663/how-to-terminate-a-python-script

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I abort the execution of a Python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179369/how-do-i-abort-the-execution-of-a-python-script)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First import these :-

```
import sys
```

Then add this after that "sorry we don't allow under 18" line

```
input('Press Enter to Continue...')
sys.exit()
```

Plus use `if` instead of `while`

Your code can be simplified as :-

```
import sys

first_name=input('PLEASE ENTER YOUR FIRST NAME: ')
last_name=input('PLEASE ENTER YOUR SURNAME: ')
print(f'Hello {first_name} {last_name}, before you enter.')

def age_det():
    age = int(input(f'How old are you?'))
    if num>=18:
        print(f'Awesome, {first_name}, welcome to Blablabla')
    else :
        print(f'Sorry, {first_name}, but we require you to be at least 18 to enter Blablabla.')
        input('Press Enter to Continue...')
        sys.exit()

age_det()
```

Comment: Why you need to do `as exiter`?

Comment: @ppwater Because if I directly do `from sys import exit` then it interfares with built-in `exit()` . So I imported it as exiter. You can use name of you choice.

Comment: Ah. okay. I think you can just do `import sys` `sys.exit()` though. importing with `from` is not good IMHO..

Comment: @ppwater yes I know that.  But why import whole `sys` when you only need `sys.exit`. Importing with `from` doesn't cause any problems. It's perfectly normal

Comment: `import exit as exiter` is totally unnecessary and very bizarre. `import sys` then call `sys.exit()` is all you need. Renaming key imports unnecessarily leads to confusing code and bugs.

Comment: I've never seen it been done this way. `sys` is routinely imported as `import sys`. You often need `sys.path`, `sys.argv` etc.

Comment: Alright, if you so much hate exiter(), I updated answer to use sys.exit().

Answer (score 1):

Import the sys object and use an if statement to check if the age is valid. If not call `sys.exit()`.

```
import sys

age = 17
if age < 18:
    sys.exit()

print("Still going") # Doesn't get printed
```

if the age is at least 18:

```
import sys

age = 25
if age < 18:
    sys.exit()

print("Still going") # Gets printed
```